# NDB query filtering by property (string)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

with ndb and the new query class to to use filter on a query you need to use the syntax like:

```
qry = MyModel.query(MyModel.title == 'title')
```

how can i query on a model without knowing in advance which properties i have to query on?

with the 'old' way i had a dictionary with keys and values to query on and looped over keys and values:

```
kwargs = {'title' : 'mytitle', 
          'age'   : 34 }

q = MyModel.all()

for kw, vals in kwargs.items():
    if not isinstance(vals, (list, tuple)):
        vals = (vals,)
    for v in vals:
        q.filter('%s =' % kw, v)
```

how could i achieve this with ndb?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it's an Expando model, or if you don't care validating the property name, you can do this easily using GenericProperty:

```
kwargs = {'title' : 'mytitle', 
          'age'   : 34 }

q = MyModel.query()

for kw, vals in kwargs.items():
    if not isinstance(vals, (list, tuple)):
        vals = (vals,)
    for v in vals:
        q = q.filter(ndb.GenericProperty(kw) == v)
```

Alternatively, if you just want to find an existing property (defined in your Model subclass) by name, you could use the _properties class attribute, e.g.

```
        q = q.filter(MyModel._properties[kw] == v)
```

or even use getattr() to get it from the class:

```
        q = q.filter(getattr(MyModel, kw) == v)
```

The difference is that getattr() uses the "Python" name of the property while _properties is indexed by the "datastore" name of the property. These only differ when the property was declared with something like

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  foo = StringProperty('bar')
```

Here the Python name is foo but the datastore name is bar.

Comment: this allowed dynamic properties. Is there a way to allow dynamic operator as well such as < and > ?

Comment: Okay, got the answer for my question above here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766150/how-to-create-a-query-for-matching-keys.
Basically, use ndb.query.FilterNode("name", "=", value) to construct filter

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t understand the purpose of `if not isinstance(vals, (list, tuple)): vals = (vals,)`. Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can still do this with a dictionary - the keys just need to be model properties instead of strings, like this:

```
kwargs = {MyModel.title : 'mytitle', 
          MyModel.age   : 34 }
q = MyModel.query()
for prop, value in kwargs.items():
  q = q.filter(prop == value)
```

Comment: I believe this is not 100% correct: [NDB query objects are immutable](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries.html#filter_by_prop). So, the last line in your code should read something like "q = q.filter(prop == value)"

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I only have the property label as a string. So no MyModel.title but only 'title' . Is there a way to get the models property by string?

Comment: @alex Oops, that's a change from db that I'd somehow missed. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: @aschmid00 You can use `getattr(MyModel, x)` to get the attribute named x. Where are you getting these filter parameters from?

Comment: Yes getattr is what I needed. I have a search() function on a model class and different handlers use it with different kwargs so the props I have to filter on differ between requests

Comment: Stupidly I didn't think of getattr... Simple as it is

Comment: @aschmid00 Is search called by your own code? If so, you could just have them pass properties rather than strings. If it ultimately comes from user code, you might want to consider building a lookup dict (from string names to properties) instead; this allows you to control which properties can be filtered on, and to give different external names to them if you wish.

Comment: @NickJohnson yes search is called by my own code. i agree with having a property lookup... atm im trying to port my code as it is to ndb because i see a lot of benefits, i'll do the fine tuning in a second step.